# Using Selenium to create a Macro Interacting with Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation

After days I've been researching I have not been able to find anything regarding my problem.
I would like to click on the text that is in this page/table but I am not able to find any values that are working.

[This is what I want the macro to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NOV5.png)

[This is what the code looks when inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSJ6T.png)

I have tried this in my code:

```
obj.FindElementByLinkText("Create PACK Material").Click
```

But I get an error saying Element not found in link text. Therefore could someone please help me out and try to figure out how i can be able to click on that "Create PACK Material" text so that it can open?

Thank you soo much. It's been days i'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding by xpath?

```
//a[contains(text(),'Create PACK Material')]
```

It's case sensitive - so maybe even try 'PACK' to see if you can get a match.

Additionally - what's "obj"?  - is that your driver or have you already identified a parent object and you're looking for the child within it?